# Encoding issue in reading CSV Latin1 file

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm with a problem reading a CSV file. My Django app (Python 2) uses coding **utf-8** and is trying to read a **latin1** CSV file.

```
# Open file
file = open(file_name)
content = file.readlines()
# content[0]
'\xff\xfeR\x00a\x00f\x00a\x00e\x00l\x00 \x00V\x00i\x00v\x00o\x00 \x00P\x00R\x00\n'
# content[0] is <type 'str'>
# I need real text: u'Rafael Vivo PR'
```

I tryied some encoding/decoding functions, but not with success.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like UTF-16 with BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is UTF-16 encoded data:

```
content = file.read().decode('utf-16').splitlines()
# u'Rafael Vivo PR'
```